# Error : Continue "Outside of Loop" in python

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

#**Mark the continue statement. I want to bring the control to the beginning of the if-elif condition. so that if user chooses excel after choosing csv , without closing exiting from the window. The label gets updated accordingly on the "root" window.** #

```
    # importing tkinter and tkinter.ttk and all their functions and classes 

    import tkinter
    import tkinter.ttk
    import os
    import sys
    import time

    # importing askopenfile function from class filedialog 

    from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile

    root = tkinter.Tk()
    root.geometry('400x200')
    root.title("CR7 - GSM BSC - Automation Tool ")
    label = tkinter.Label(root, text ="Please Select the CR7 Input file for Generating Scripts").pack#(side="top", pady=10)

    # This function will be used to open file in read mode and only excel & csv can be  opened 
    def open_file():
        file = askopenfile(mode='r', filetypes=[('CSV Files', '*.csv'),('Excel 2003', '*.xls'),('Excel 2007', '*.xlsx')])
        filepathstring = str(file)
        if filepathstring.find("xls") > 1 or filepathstring.find("xlsx") > 1 and  filepathstring.find("csv") <1 :
            label1 = tkinter.Label(root, text="Selected file is 'Excel' File & will be converted to 'CSV' file ").pack(side="top",pady=40)
            continue
        elif filepathstring.find("xls") < 1 or filepathstring.find("xlsx") < 1 and  filepathstring.find("csv") > 1 :
            label2 = tkinter.Label(root, text="Selected file is 'csv' File  ").pack(side="top", pady=20)
            continue
    btn = tkinter.Button(root, command=lambda: open_file(), text='Open').pack(side="top", pady=10)

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: First `askopenfile()` will return a open file object, not the filename.  You should use `askopenfilename()` instead.  Second you can only select one file each time the `Open` button is clicked, so what do you mean *"chooses excel after choosing csv"*?

Comment: thanks @acw1668 for the first suggestion . Yes my idea is to select one file at a time. I wanted to put a label in the window on the basis of the file chosen..But if somehow one choses wrong filetype & decides to correct it by choosing another file while the same file dialog is open. then the error occurs.....i.e. label printed during first time file choosing stays while switching to another filetype . so i wanted to restart the loop basically to avoid this error.

Comment: Then you should create the message label once outside `open_file()` and update its text inside the function instead.  But **don't** create it like `label1 = tkinter.Label(...).pack(...)` because `label1` will be `None`.  Separate the statements into two: `label1 = tkinter.Label(...)` and `label1.pack(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to update the first label. Your issue is that you are packing the widgets before creating the reference variable. The python run time environment first creates the widgets; executes the .pack() method; then assigns the variable the results of the .pack() method which is None. Once you have a working reference you can use the .configure() method to change the text value. I didn't run the code, so if there are any issues pleas leave a comment, so I can correct.

```py
# importing tkinter and tkinter.ttk and all their functions and classes 

    import tkinter
    import tkinter.ttk
    import os
    import sys
    import time

    # importing askopenfile function from class filedialog 

    from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile

    root = tkinter.Tk()
    root.geometry('400x200')
    root.title("CR7 - GSM BSC - Automation Tool ")
    label = tkinter.Label(root, text ="Please Select the CR7 Input file for Generating Scripts")
    label.pack(side="top", pady=10) # Packing the label before you create a reference creates a reference to the return value of .pack() method which is None
    btn = tkinter.Button(root, command=open_file, text='Open') # you don't need to use lambda unless passing a variable
    btn.pack(side="top", pady=10)

    # This function will be used to open file in read mode and only excel & csv can be  opened 
    def open_file():
        file = askopenfile(mode='r', filetypes=[('CSV Files', '*.csv'),('Excel 2003', '*.xls'),('Excel 2007', '*.xlsx')])
        filepathstring = str(file)
        if filepathstring.find("xls") > 1 or filepathstring.find("xlsx") > 1 and  filepathstring.find("csv") <1 :
            label.configure(text="Selected file is 'Excel' File & will be converted to 'CSV' file ")
        elif filepathstring.find("xls") < 1 or filepathstring.find("xlsx") < 1 and  filepathstring.find("csv") > 1 :
            label.configure(text="Selected file is 'csv' File  ")

    root.mainloop()
```